# don't want to display password in address bar in html

Tags: html

Username:
    Password:

**/users/home** is html file displayed on submit button

when I enter username and password as "anuj" and "rohan"
they are displayed on the next page in the address bar as http://localhost:3000/users/home?**username=anuj&pwd=rohan**

I don't want to display these things as these are protected. Is there any way to encrypt or hide passwords in html.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use the `form` tag, make sure it's `method` attribute is set to `POST` like so:

```
<form action="index.php" method=POST>
```

Comment: And since he's talking about encryption you may want to look into HTTPS and SSL

Comment: @Robert can you give me some code or site link where  i can see how to use https or ssl for making password encryption

Comment: @user818146 here is a link explaining HTTP and SSL: http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/https.html